# Find and split Multipolygons in spatialite

Tags: qgis, spatialite, spatialite-gui

I have a spatialite table with more than 1100 Polygons. The geometry type in that table is multipolygon. There are only some real Multipolygons inside and I need only polygons. How can I find the multiparts? How can I split the multiparts?
Also are there some polygons without geometry. What is the way to identify them?
I want to do that work in the database but could do it also in QGIS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SpatiaLite, you can use the function ElementaryGeometries such as the following code :

```
SELECT ElementaryGeometries('multipoly', 'geom', 'singlepoly','gid','fid') as geom
FROM multipoly
```

This function create a new table *singlepoly* where each multipolygon of the table *multipoly* is converted to a simple polygon. For example, I had one feature. For example, I had a multi-polygon with 4 features. On output, I get a table with 4 rows.

In QGIS, you can use the following tool : 
`Vector > Geometry tools > Multipart to Singleparts`.

Comment: SpatiaLite does have a function for that and it is called ElementaryGeometries https://www.gaia-gis.it/stored-procs-win-test/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

Comment: Thank you, you're right! I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helps. There are some additional questions:
How could I identify and select the rows with multiparts?
How coul I copy/save the polygons from the table with geom MULTIPOLYGON into a table with geom POLYGON?

Comment: You-re welcome! You can accept my answer if it helped you! I advise you to open a new post to ask your question.