# Find multipolygons in spatialite

Tags: spatialite

How could I identify and select the rows with multiparts? 
How could I copy/save the polygons from a table with geom MULTIPOLYGON into a table with geom POLYGON?

Answer (score 1):

Read http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html

Find function ST_GeometryType.
Use it like

```
SELECT * from my_table
WHERE ST_GeometryType(GEOMETRY)='MULTIPOLYGON';
```

How to create a new table with ElementaryGeometries has an answer already in [Find and split Multipolygons in spatialite](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350711/find-and-split-multipolygons-in-spatialite/350713) and the usage of the ElementaryGeometries function is

```
SELECT ElementaryGeometries('input_table','input_geometry','output_table','new_id_1', 'new_id_2');
```

The ElementaryGeometries is a special function and it requires that the input table is a real table (not a view) that has its spatial metadata inserted into SpatiaLite database.

Thus creating a new table from just multipolygons requires some interim steps.

```
CREATE TABLE interim as
SELECT * from input_table 
WHERE ST_GeometryType(GEOMETRY)='MULTIPOLYGON';
```

Then use RecoverGeometryColumn as documented in https://www.gaia-gis.it/stored-procs-win-test/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

And finally convert multipolygons from the interim table into polygons into a final table

```
SELECT ElementaryGeometries('interim','GEOMETRY','final_table','new_id_1', 'new_id_2');
```

It may feel a bit complicated to do this task with SpatiaLite but all the steps can be written into a script. But I wonder why you want to find just the multipolygons. It would be much easies to push the whole table with both polygons and multipolygons through ElementaryGeometries.

Myself I guess I would do your exact task of selecting and exploding multipolygons with ogr2ogr https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html

Comment: I try to use `ElementaryGeometries` on a whole table which is in a spatiaLite database. The geometry column on final table is empty with `select ElementaryGeometries('polyligne', "GEOMETRY", 'test', "pk","id") as GEOMETRY from polyligne`. I am using the DBM of QGIS 3.16. Any idea ?

Comment: The syntax of ElementaryGeometries is not like `select .. from`. The input and output tables are used as arguments. See the example and documentation (I corrected the link) http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

Comment: Thanks. I had 2 mistakes : the `FROM` and the `out_multi_id` field whose name must be unique.