# How to Multipart to Singlepart a QGIS virtual-layer?

Tags: qgis, spatialite, virtual-layer, dbmanager

I have a polygon layer I want to explode into single lines. I preferably wish to do so in spatialite since I work almost exclusively in QGIS DB-manager. No matter which function I use the number of features stays the same:

```
ST_DissolveSegments(st_boundary(geometry))

ST_LinesCutAtNodes(st_boundary(geometry),st_dissolvepoints(geometry))
```

Now there is also that concept of [ElementaryGeometries](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/info/d6069e7bf8c7f124) which is spatialite specific and does not seem to be implemented in geopackage or QGIS virtual layers (please correct me if I am wrong here). Also there's [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/350713/86042) that I honestly fail to follow due to sparse documentation as well as on whether this is implemented in QGIS' DB-manager environment or not.

I know there's a bunch of native tools that do the job but I'd really love to keep my workflow streamlined and avoid intermediate result layer as much as possible.

Comment: I don't think it is easily possible (yet), and you may have to rely on using a geoprocessing tool instead of a virtual layer. There is a way to achieve it using recursive queries, have a look at this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381187/convert-vertices-of-polygon-features-to-points-using-virtual-layer-in-qgis/381247#381247)

Comment: TY, bookmarked. Morbidly fascinating. Successfully tested, adoption for exploding lines pending.

Comment: Maybe the ST_Dump() function helps https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html

Comment: ST_Dump does not work for spatialite/Virtual Layer at this point. I agree, CTE/recursive queries seem to be the only way forward for now. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/341570/98784 for another example